# In an AM radio do the electromagnetic waves cause the antenna to resonate to produce an alternating current?

Tags: rf, radio, electromagnetic

Looking at Hertz's original experiment with electromagnetic waves with the spark gap how did he know how to build his antenna size to receive the wave that generated the spark ? In what way is the AM antenna like a spark gap receiver? There is no spark from within the antenna is there ?  So then any metal object will produce an AC current when an electromagnetic wave hits it? And an antenna is constructed to resonate at some particular frequencies in order to amplify the signal?  Basically I am trying to understand what makes an antenna an antenna so to speak.

Comment: Hertz's work was at 60 Megahertz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A current will be created in any length of wire that is subjected to a moving electromagnetic field. How much current is created depends on the potential difference in space along that wire.

The length of the wire vs the wavelength of the signal determines how much potential is along that wire. Obviously if the wire is short in comparison to the wavelength, not much current will be generated in the wire. If it is exactly half a wave length long, the maximum potential difference will be achieved and maximum current will flow.

So yes, you can design an antenna to work best at a particular frequency. However, they still work at other frequencies but produce less signal.

AM radios are fairly low frequency and a have a long wavelength. You would need an antenna more than 200m long. As such you can not tune it that way. Further, you want to pickup various frequencies so you can listen to multiple stations so tuning an antenna would be a bad thing even if you could.

As for Hertz's experiment, a spark causes a very wideband radio pulse which is detectable by pretty much any piece of wire.

Answer (score 7):

> Looking at Hertz's original experiment with electromagnetic waves with the spark gap how did he know how to build his antenna size to receive the wave that generated the spark ?

First of all, the spark doesn't have a "single" frequency/wavelength. It's an extremely broadband emitter, so he could have chosen any length within a large range.

Then, Hertz came **after** Maxwell - so, all the math was known to him (though he went through great efforts of making that math usable, and teachable to students, as he was the first generation of EE professors in the world, and taught EM theory, as well as half of the rest of the EE curriculum at the University of Karlsruhe). So, he's the one to describe the Hertzian Dipole as model for an "infinitesimal antenna element" – and thus was also able to model the antenna as an array of those, leading to a frequency selective antenna.

> In what way is the AM antenna like a spark gap receiver?

There's no such thing as an "AM antenna". AM is a modulation. Antennas are selective for carrier frequencies and signal bandwidths.

In any way, an antenna is just a conductor that gets excited by EM fields.

> So then any metal object will produce an AC current when an electromagnetic wave hits it?

"produce": no. have a current induced internally: yes, as long as the wave doesn't hit it perfectly in an angle that leads to the conductor extending only in a direction of constant E-field.

> And an antenna is constructed to resonate at some particular frequencies in order to amplify the signal?

"amplify": no. pick up the wave's energy at that frequency: yes.

> Basically I am trying to understand what makes an antenna an antenna so to speak.

Antenna Theory – it's a large field, and you should probably start reading a textbook. Probably, amateur radio clubs do have beginner-friendly intros to antennas.

Comment: In simple terms the antenna guides the power from free space to the receiver.   It does this by matching the impedance of free space so that the maximum power can be transferred to the receiver.  The earth plane creates a duplicate, mirror image of the antenna to increase the effectiveness.

Comment: @skvery I agree with your "the antenna is an impedance transformer from free space to transmission line impedance", but your second sentence doesn't apply to all antennas – what you refer to here is a monopole, and OP didn't mention one, as far as I can see.